# xslt: whats the easiest way to do a negated selection?

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon, xslt-3.0, xpath-3.0

Basically what I would like is something like this that finds all nodes where the ID cannot be lookup'ed up ('broken links') :

```
<xsl:variable name="failedIDLookups" select="//inventory/box[@boxtypeID != //boxtypes/@ID]"/>
```

But this is not working as expected - I suppose the syntax is wrong, what should be the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'broken ID'?

Comment: @Andersson missed lookups

Comment: Can you share snippet of your input data ? It will make clear idea on what you exactly want to do.

Comment: `xsl:key` is the best option and faster in execution as answered by @Martin

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534882/how-do-i-specify-not-equals-to-when-comparing-strings-in-an-xslt-xslif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you want

```
<xsl:variable name="failedIDLookups" select="//inventory/box[not(@boxtypeID = //boxtypes/@ID)]"/>
```

which then could be optimized with a key declaration (as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`)

```
<xsl:key name="boxtypes-ref" match="boxtypes" use="@ID"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:variable name="failedIDLookups" select="//inventory/box[not(key('boxtypes-ref', @boxtypeID))]"/>
```