# XSLT Identity transform - copy parent based on child value, without copying other children

Tags: xslt, copy, transform

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
        <peci:Summary>
            <peci:Integration_Event>6d374dcbe3a81024090d271cab840000</peci:Integration_Event>
        </peci:Summary>
        <peci:Worker>
            <peci:Worker_Summary>
                <peci:Employee_ID>328556</peci:Employee_ID>
            </peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-27T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-27T03:24:11.531-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>              
            </peci:Effective_Change>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="1">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-27T03:30:05.861-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-27T03:30:05.861-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
        </peci:Worker>
        <peci:Worker>
            <peci:Worker_Summary>
                <peci:Employee_ID>328557</peci:Employee_ID>
            </peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-27T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-27T04:44:30.864-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>              
            </peci:Effective_Change>
        </peci:Worker>
        <peci:Worker>
            <peci:Worker_Summary>
                <peci:Employee_ID>1111132</peci:Employee_ID>
            </peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-25T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-25T04:44:30.864-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>              
            </peci:Effective_Change>
        </peci:Worker>
    </peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
</peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate>
```

I would like to get something like (only employees with hire event and only an event that is a hire):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
   <peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
      <peci:Summary>
         <peci:Integration_Event>6d374dcbe3a81024090d271cab840000</peci:Integration_Event>
      </peci:Summary>
      <peci:Worker>
         <peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Employee_ID>328556</peci:Employee_ID>
         </peci:Worker_Summary>
         <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-27T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-27T03:24:11.531-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
         </peci:Effective_Change>
      </peci:Worker>
      <peci:Worker>
         <peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Employee_ID>328557</peci:Employee_ID>
         </peci:Worker_Summary>
         <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-27T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-27T04:44:30.864-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
         </peci:Effective_Change>
      </peci:Worker>
   </peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
</peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate>
```

This is my code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   
    <xsl:template match='peci:Effective_Change[peci:Derived_Event_Code != "HIR"]'/>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately it does not remove the worker without HIR event code (the last one). I tried adding this

```
 <xsl:template match="peci:Worker[peci:Effective_Change/peci:Derived_Event_Code!='HIR']"/>
```

but it removed the first worker (with two transactions as well).

Thanks in advance

Przemek

Answer (score 0):

Ok I needed

```
<xsl:template match="peci:Worker[not(peci:Effective_Change/peci:Derived_Event_Code='HIR')]"/>
```

but can someone explain why?

Comment: You might find the explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534882/how-do-i-specify-not-equals-to-when-comparing-strings-in-an-xslt-xslif/10536840#10536840 helpful